# jax-rs y Spring - No funciona la descarga de archivos, sale mensaje de error

Tags: java, spring, rest, jax-rs

Estoy implementando un servicio web que permita **descargar un archivo** enviando su **nombre** y su **tipo de archivo**. Cuando lo pruebo, el servicio encuentra el archivo correctamente; pero al momento de la respuesta, me está saliendo el siguiente mensaje:

> **No message body writer has been found for class org.springframework.http.ResponseEntity, ContentType: */***

Este es mi código de descarga de archivos, el método **getFilePath(Request)** trae la ruta del archivo para ser descargado en un **org.springframework.http.ResponseEntity**, cuyo *body* es una instancia **org.springframework.core.io.InputStreamResource**.

```
@Path("/file")
public class FileHandlerWS {
    // Código previo    
    @POST
    @Consumes(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
    @Path("/download")
    public ResponseEntity<InputStreamResource> downloadFile(DownloadFileRequest request) {
        ResponseEntity<InputStreamResource> response;
        BodyBuilder bodyBuilder;
        List<String> errorMessages;
        errorMessages = this.getErrorMessages(request);
        try {
            File file = new File(this.getFilePath(request));
            InputStreamResource resource = new InputStreamResource(new FileInputStream(file));
            if (errorMessages.isEmpty()) {
                response = ResponseEntity.ok().contentLength(file.length())
                        .header(HttpHeaders.CONTENT_DISPOSITION,
                                this.generics.getFileContentDispositionAttachment(request.getFilename()))
                        .contentType(MediaType.APPLICATION_OCTET_STREAM)
                        .body(resource);
            } else {
                bodyBuilder = ResponseEntity.badRequest();
                response = bodyBuilder.build();
            }
        } catch (IOException ex) {
            bodyBuilder = ResponseEntity.status(HttpStatus.INTERNAL_SERVER_ERROR);
            bodyBuilder.body(ex);
            response = bodyBuilder.build();
        }
        return response;
    }
    // Código posterior
}
```

Y, en el archivo de configuración, se han habilitado dos *providers*: **JacksonJsonProvider**, para respuestas tipo REST; y **FileProvider** para descargas.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<beans  xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
        xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
        xmlns:jaxws="http://cxf.apache.org/jaxws"
        xmlns:jaxrs="http://cxf.apache.org/jaxrs"
        xmlns:context="http://www.springframework.org/schema/context"
        xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans
                            http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans.xsd
                            http://cxf.apache.org/jaxws
                            http://cxf.apache.org/schemas/jaxws.xsd
                            http://cxf.apache.org/jaxrs
                            http://cxf.apache.org/schemas/jaxrs.xsd
                            http://www.springframework.org/schema/context  
                            http://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-context.xsd">

    <import resource="datasource.xml"/>
    <import resource="context.xml"/>
    <import resource="security.xml"/>

    <!-- Habilita el uso de anotaciones Spring -->
    <context:annotation-config />

    <!-- Paquete principal, que contiene todas las clases que el sistema utilizará. -->
    <context:component-scan base-package="pe"/>

    <!-- Archivo interno de propiedades. -->
    <context:property-placeholder
        location="classpath:generic.properties,classpath:logger.properties,
                  file:C:\Users\user\props\ext.properties" ignore-unresolvable="true" />

    <!-- Controladores principales -->
    <bean id="service" class="pe.NaughtClockWS" init-method="init" />
    <bean id="file" class="pe.FileHandlerWS" />

    <!-- Implementación básica del protocolo REST, basado en JSON -->
    <bean id="jsonProvider" class="org.codehaus.jackson.jaxrs.JacksonJsonProvider" />

    <!-- Para carga/descarga de archivos -->
    <bean id="fileProvider" class="org.jboss.resteasy.plugins.providers.FileProvider"/>

    <jaxrs:server id="cliente" address="/">
        <jaxrs:serviceBeans>
            <ref bean="service" />
            <ref bean="file" />
        </jaxrs:serviceBeans>
        <jaxrs:providers>
            <ref bean='jsonProvider' />
            <ref bean="fileProvider" />
        </jaxrs:providers>
    </jaxrs:server>

 </beans>
```

¿Está mal utilizado el FileProvider? ¿O qué otra clase debería utilizar en su lugar?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hola el provider que estas usando no soporta `InputStreamResource`, puede ver lo que soporta en el siguiente enlace https://docs.oracle.com/cd/E19798-01/821-1841/6nmq2cp1v/index.html

Puedes usar por ejemplo `StreamingOutput`

Espero sea lo que estes buscando sino me puedes escribir para ayudarte a resolver tus dudas.

, saludos.